# getattr(): attribute name must be string in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

from Django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.

class postingmodel(models.Model):
    Post_Title=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Post_Content=models.TextField(max_length=500)
    datetime=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to='static', height_field=400, width_field=400)
```

Here, I created models
Django-admin couldn't save that post and show error like this

getattr(): attribute name must be a string in Django

Comment: please share the StackTrace. And please donot declare variables like that (capitalized first character), please follow the naming convention https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles

Answer (score 2):

Remove `height_field=400`, `width_field=400`, As Django Doc describes:

**`ImageField.height_field`**

> Name of a model field which will be
> auto-populated with the height of the image each time the model
> instance is saved.

**`ImageField.width_field`**

> Name of a model field which will be
> auto-populated with the width of the image each time the model
> instance is saved

One possible use case for `height_field` and `width_field` could be like this:

```
class postingmodel(models.Model):
    Post_Title=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Post_Content=models.TextField(max_length=500)
    datetime=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to='static', height_field='height', width_field='width')
    height = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

The `height` and `width` fields will be auto populated if your uploaded images has height and width attributes available